# Silverstripe 3 - LeftAndMain::ForceReload

Tags: silverstripe

I need to reload the content area in the admincenter after deleting a dataobject.
This dataobject is managed inside an Inline-Editing-Gridfield.

That's the my code on the dataobject

```
public function onAfterDelete(){
    parent::onAfterDelete();

    if( Session::get('ShopReloadAdminPage') ){
        Session::clear('ShopReloadAdminPage');
        return LeftAndMain::ForceReload();
    }
}
```

The Problem is, that this only reloads the Inline-Grid and makes it disappear.

Does someone know how to achieve this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LeftAndMain::ForceReload() doesn't exist in SilverStripe 3+. I'd guess the reason your GridField is disappearing is because its throwing an error when you call it.

Comment: ok that would explain this. but is there a way to force a reload?

Comment: You'd need to dig into the core to see how its done there. An example of an ajax response can be found here: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.1/admin/code/LeftAndMain.php#L470